# How to create a partition in C

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, partitioning, partition

How to create an partition and set it's size with **C** in linux?

Comment: There is a description of the *task*, but what is a **question**? We definitely won't write the tool for you. Your requirement "The partition should act like an external flash drive, but:" fits almost to any filesystem - ext4, xfs, etc. And there are existing tools for work with a "partition", formatted for those filesystems. So it is not clear why do you want to write a tool.

Comment: Hello, I am building sort of remote-file-managment and I'd like to create a separate ext4 partition for each user. I originally wanted only answer on "how to programmaticaly create a partition" but there is more stuff around it. Also there isn't any clear guide on the internet yet. Thanks!

Comment: Creating an ext4 "partition" could be performed with just `mkfs -t ext4` command line. Changing the ext4 partition owner is just re-mounting it with needed owner. I would suggest you to firstly **choose** a filesystem and make sure that it supports all your requirements using existing **tools**: if something is not supported, then it is probably not supported by the filesystem at all, and writing low-level C code won't help. After that, you may try to implement behavior of these tools in C language: these tools are open sources, so you can easily look through their code.

Comment: "I'm looking for a solution in C" That would be something like `pid child = fork(); if (child == 0) { execve(externalCommandToDoWhatYouWant, commandLineArguments); }`

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. that sounds pretty easy. Do you think it will affect the performance? If I use execve() instead of writing the program myself?

Comment: Performance? How many ext4 filesystems per second do you need to create?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  I don't know the exact numbers but around 1500-1700, Of course, it will be less at night. So i want to save up some performance, if possible.

Comment: 1500-1700 filesystems per second on a single node is not something I can imagine dealing with. You may want to ask a separate question, and prominently indicate your performance requirements.

Comment: It's very fast machine, I think it will work, it's just about creating empty partition(s). I will try to look into code of some open source disk managers, but I think the code will be pretty complicated and customized for the app.

Comment: Study sourcecode for existing tools.